# How to set value in Ruby to text field with AutoPostBack on site in ASP

Tags: ruby, watir, autopostback

I have website written in ASP with searchTextBox with AutoPostBack and searchButton to search for value entered in searchTextBox.
Here is the code:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="searchTextBox" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" Width="159px">enter value</asp:TextBox>                        
<asp:Button ID="searchButton" runat="server" Text="Search" Width="151px" 
                    onclick="searchButton_Click" />
```

I would like to search for certain values using Ruby.
Here is my code:

```
search=@brows.text_field(:id=>'searchTextBox')
search.set(name)
@btnSearch=@brows.button(:id=>'searchButton')
@btnSearch.click
```

When I run script, value is entered, but before button is clicked it disapears.
How to stop this value disappearing?
When I do this manually value doesn't disappear. It is successfully send to next form.